# Xdebug 3 on Windows server via VSCode remote connection

Tags: php, xdebug, windows-server, vscode-remote, xdebug-3

I'm almost there but this last bit is driving me crazy.

I have a Windows Server with PHP Xdebug installed. Xdebug config:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=10.0.1.11
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

In my VSCode, remotely connected to my Windows Server, I've installed the Xdebug extension. This is my config:

```json
{
  "name": "Listen for XDebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "hostname": "10.0.1.11",
  "port": 9003,
  "pathMappings": {
    "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
  },
  "log": true
}
```

Now, I know I'm close because if I add `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` to my Xdebug config, I can see the connections appearing on my VSCode debug output (since the log is on).

I can't get it to break on my breakpoints though. I also see them in the logs, but when I make a request it just goes through without stopping.
(and I'm sure the code with the breakpoint is called. I confirmed it with a good old fashioned `die()`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log in php.ini and try to debug -- it should show where it tries to connect to, what the interactions are, breakpoints the the debug client sets (VSCode in this case). Maybe breakpoints are not getting set at all .. or in the wrong files/lines. 2) Could be wrong path mapping issue. Especially if no breakpoints are set.